# Make hidden header reappear when user stops scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, sticky

I'm currently using the code below to hide the header when the user scrolls down, and show it again when they scroll up. It's functioning well, however I would like to append it so that, as well as reappearing on scroll-up, the header also reappears when the user has stopped scrolling for a specified amount of time.

Any help much appreciated.

Current code -

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
}
}, 50);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function which will check if the user stops scrolling. Then you could handle your logic to display your header in the callback function.

```
...
// @param  {Function} callback The callback function to run after scrolling
// @param  {Integer}  refresh  How long to wait between scroll events [optional]
function scrollStop (callback, refresh = 60) {
    // Make sure a valid callback was provided
    if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') return;

    // Setup scrolling variable
    let isScrolling;

    // Listen for scroll events
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {

        // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
        window.clearTimeout(isScrolling);

        // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
        isScrolling = setTimeout(callback, refresh);

    }, false);

}

scrollStop(function () {
    // logic to display header here
    $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    console.log('Scrolling has stopped.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgive me but I'm very much a novice when it comes to coding, I can see what your code is meant to do but how would I append this into my original code to work?

Comment: Try to copy the code and paste it into your file. "..." should be your old code

Comment: Ah yes, I did this but missed a curly bracket... it works perfectly! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Having tried this out I'm actually not keen on the UX. What I would prefer would be for the header to reappear when the mouse pointer in near the top of the window. Is this possible?

Comment: You could create a hover event listener for your navbar and then let your navbar reappear if the user over over the navbar
$( "header" ).hover(function() {
 $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
});

Comment: Yeah that's where I was heading, however this doesn't work as the header is already hidden so you can't mouse over it

Comment: I got this working well in the end, I pointed the event listener to a button instead that reveals the header nav. Thanks for all your help!